# Auto Scrolling in Adobe Reader with middle click lock

Tags: mouse, scrolling, adobe-reader

In firefox (or may be in other browsers also), I middle click (and release the button) and there appears a cross hair/4 or 2 direction pointer. And now I just have to move my pointer in any direction, without clicking any button, and it'll scroll in that direction. And the distance to the cross-hair, will decide the acceleration/speed of the scroll.

Is this functionality absent in the late versions of Adobe Reader, or was it never there? Is it possible to bring back that setting easily by some way?

[image: screen shot of the cross hair that appeared on middle click]

Comment: It was never there IMHO

Comment: Oh!! But since it works in all browsers, and all Ms Office wares, I (perhaps) presumed that it worked (or should work) here also. Btw, if I keep the middle button pressed, then it does work in Adobe reader also.